# Get value from a cell in a closed workbook, file name made up of variables

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to return the Value of a cell in a closed workbook whose name is made up of variables something like this:

```
="'C:\" & x & ".13\" & y & "\[CSD m activity " & B1 & ".xlsx]Tracking'!B4"
```

where   x=6,        y=6.1

Which I want to return the value of B4 in the worksheet named Tracking in the file

```
'C:\6.13\6.1\[CSD m activity 6.1.xlsx]Tracking'!B4
```

My code returns the file name as a string, but I want the Value in the file, is there a way to do this with or without VBA, anything will help
Thanks!

Comment: The only way I know of getting data out of a closed workbook is to either open it or make an ADODB connection and query it using SQL.

Comment: if the other workbook is open you can use `=INDIRECT(..` otherwise you will need VBA afaik

Answer (score 0):

You can get a value from a closed workbook in VBA:

```
Debug.Print ExecuteExcel4Macro("'F:\Documents and Settings\student\My Documents\[AndysData7.xlsx]Staff List'!R6C4")
```

The formula needs to be in R1C1 format.

This is an undocumented feature though, and may not work in future Excel versions.

Comment: But lets say I wanted to do it from 1 of 10 files named "AndysData1" "AndysData2", etc, and what if the folder route each was in was different, basically i want the file path to be a variable

Comment: You can construct your string in a variable and pass it to `ExecuteExcel4Macro()` in a loop.